# How to break simulation on VHDL severity ERROR or WARNING in Riviera-Pro

Tags: vhdl

By default the riviera simulator stops on severity level FAILURE. Depending on the test bench I want to break on either ERROR or WARNING. Aldec themselves state that this can be done using a `breakassertlevel` TCL variable:
https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/faq/1070

Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. I have tried setting this variable both before loading the top level with `vsim` and before running the simulation with `run`. Setting the variable to 2 has absolutely no effect and simulation continues past an assert with severity level ERROR.

Also one would also expect this variable to exist and be set to 3 (FAILURE) by default but that is not the case.

Thus I am left wondering if I am doing something wrong or if I have simply found documentation of a dead feature. Anyone else have experience using the `breakassertlevel` TCL variable or using some other mechanism to achieve the same result?

I am not interested in solutions which involve manually changing some setting in a GUI since I need to control this in a batch flow. Also different test benches need to stop on WARNING while others need to stop on ERROR so setting it "once and for all" is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Aldec support team:

*For Riviera-PRO please use vhdlassert command instead i.e.:*

*vhdlassert.break error*